Why doesn't my custom configuration appear in new projects in Visual Studio?
I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution with projects written in C++. In addition to the default Debug and Release configurations, I created a custom configuration called Release_No_Opt by copying the settings from Release. This configuration is similar to Release, but with optimizations disabled and some other minor adjustments. The existing projects are already set up to include this custom configuration.

However, for example, when I create a new DLL project, I can only see the Release and Debug configurations.

